# Wait 60 seconds before sending the captured SSID to the server

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I am implementing a Tracking service to track the location of buses in  my city. The buses are equipped with `WIFI access point (AP)`. So I will the detect the route number based on the SSID of the WIFI AP after parsing it from the JSON text document. I have implemented a BroadcastReceiver to do the job but to avoid the case that the bus holds close to the user for a moment and the user does not enter the bus (maybe because the bus is not the right bus the user is waiting for) I want to send the  route to the server after 60 seconds. So the app must capture the SSID for the first time and then check whether it is still in range after 60 seconds and then in this case the route is being sent to the server. How can I do that in my case?

I appreciate any help.

**Part of the JSON document:**

```
{
    "wifi": [
             {
              "ssid": "Fr Privat",
              "route_number": 1
             },

             {
               "ssid": "Fr WLAN Hotspot+",
               "route_number": 4
             }
           ]
}
```

**TrackingService class:**

```
    public class TrackingService extends Service implements
            LocationListener {
        private int route_number = 0;

        private final BroadcastReceiver wifi_receiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

                WifiManager wifi = (WifiManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
                if (wifi.isWifiEnabled()) {
                    WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
                    final List<ScanResult> results = wifiManager.getScanResults();
                    if (results != null) {
                        // list of access points from the last scan
                        List<ScanResult> updatedResults = new ArrayList<ScanResult>();
                        // pick Wi-Fi access points which begins with these "Fr"
                        // characters.
                        for (int i = 0; i < results.size(); i++) {
                            String ssid = results.get(i).SSID;
                            if (ssid.startsWith("Fr")) {
                                updatedResults.add(results.get(i));
                            }
                        }
                        if (updatedResults.size() > 0 && route_number == 0) {
                            String ssid = deliverBestAccessPoint(updatedResults);
                            // retrieve data from json String and parse it.
                            route_number = parse_SSID(ssid);

                        }
                    } 

                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(context, "Please turn your Wi-Fi on",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }

            }
        private String deliverBestAccessPoint(final List<ScanResult> updatedResults) {
            ScanResult bestSignal = (ScanResult) updatedResults.get(0);
            for (int i = 1; i < updatedResults.size(); i++) {
                ScanResult result = (ScanResult) updatedResults.get(i);
                bestSignal = (WifiManager.compareSignalLevel(bestSignal.level,
                        result.level) < 0) ? result : bestSignal;
            }
            return bestSignal.SSID;
         }   

        }; 

        @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        if (location != null) {
      ......
                String jSONString = convertToJSON(mac, pLong, pLat, time, speed);
                if (isNetworkAvailable()) {
                PostData sender = new PostData(TrackingService.this);
                sender.post_data(jSONString, this);

            }

    }
}


    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Handler](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html) class to delay the SSID being sent to the Server by 60 sec.

Everytime you get a SSID you invoke the [postDelayed()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html#postDelayed(java.lang.Runnable,%20long)) function with your custom [Runnable](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Runnable.html) and your delay of 60 secs.

Inside the Runnable you check whether the SSID is in range or not,if it is in range then send the SSID to the Server.

Hope this helps